# Deep Learning Prediction Result's Range(BPSK)

Tags: python, deep-learning

I work on a ML program and I need to understand why my prediction result is in range of 0 and 1 .My result should be -1 or 1 for BPSK.In the code prediction result is always become 0 for -1,can ı solvethis problem.
My code is:

```
# first neural network with keras tutorial
import pandas 
from numpy import genfromtxt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
# load the dataset
dataset = genfromtxt("C:/Users/Kerim/Desktop/dataset/snr_10_tau_09/t.csv",dtype=complex 
,delimiter=",")
X = dataset[:,0:5]
y = dataset[:,5]
# define the keras model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=5, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit the keras model on the dataset
model.fit(X, y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
# evaluate the keras model
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(X, y)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
predictions = model.predict_classes(X)
# summarize the first 5 cases
for i in range(0,900,90):
   print('%s => %d (expected %d)' % (X[i].tolist(), predictions[i], y[i]))
```

And my prediction output is:

```
**[0j, (-1+0j), (-0.25207-0.26366j), (-1.1735-0.027089j), (-1.1735-0.027089j)] => 0 (expected -1)
  [0j, (-1+0j), (0.0080991+0.14503j), (-0.87461+0.016972j), (-0.87461+0.016972j)] => 0 (expected -1)
  [(1+0j), (1+0j), (0.25098-0.31795j), (1.1745+0.23413j), (1.1745+0.23413j)] => 1 (expected 1)
  [0j, (-1+0j), (-0.22237+0.25802j), (-1.4702+0.63253j), (-1.4702+0.63253j)] => 0 (expected -1)
  [0j, (-1+0j), (-0.25788+0.087908j), (-0.88608-0.11732j), (-0.88608-0.11732j)] => 0 (expected -1)
  [(1+0j), (1+0j), (0.0062392-0.3863j), (1.0404+0.033856j), (1.0404+0.033856j)] => 1 (expected 1)**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the prediction is in `(0, 1)` because your final activation is a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function). Sigmoid transforms values to a range `(0, 1)`.

You have at least two options to fix this:

1. Use `tanh` as the final activation function. The output is in `(-1, 1)`.
2. Transform your labels to `(0, 1)`.

Comment: I tried tanh before but ı got sam result.And now ı try again ı get 100 percent accurycy is it normal or bug? @jakub in addition my result still in range of 0 and 1